# Make CKEditor dialog scrollable?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

My dialog contains a tree, it can spread the window vertically and can be cut by the screen size. Is it possible to add a vertical scrollbar to the dialog in CKEditor?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should be able to use CSS.

Comment: You will need to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks, I used CSS: `<div id="root" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 300px;"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no scrollbar in CKEditor dialogs unfortunately. You could try using the https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/iframedialog dialog which enables you having iframe inside the dialog which can use the scrollbar. You could try obtaining the dialog object and resizing it whenever tree size changes. Please note that in this case you would probably need to enable scrollbar in your page when dialog gets too big.

In order to capture the dialog, you can use `dialogDefinition` event - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#event-dialogDefinition. Once you have the dialog (`evt.data.definition.dialog`) reference, you can later use the resize method - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog.html#method-resize

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
let dialogName = ev.data.name;
let dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
let editor = ev.editor;
      
dialogDefinition.onShow = () => {
    var body = $( ".cke_dialog_body");
    body.css( "height", "700px" );
    body.css("overflow", "scroll")
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).